# How would I re-write this expression using the function composition (.) /application ($) operators?

Tags: haskell

I've been trying very hard to grasp the `(.)` and `($)` operators in Haskell. I believe I understand the differences between them well enough, but I am still having a hard time successfully replacing the parentheses in my expressions with these operators.

For example, if I have the expression

```
print(show(take 5 [1..10]))
```

I understand how to rewrite it using the `(.)` and `($)` operators

```
print . show . take 5 $ [1..10]
```

However, if I had something like

```
print (show (take (snd (1,5)) [1..10]))
```

The furthest I can simplify this down to is

```
print . show . take (snd (1,5)) $ [1..10]
```

No matter what I try I can not seem to replace those inner parenthesis with the `($)` or `(.)` operator and have it successfully compile. I understand that most Haskellers typically use the `($)` and `(.)` operators over parentheses so I am trying really hard to follow that style as well. If someone could point out how I could rewrite that expression above without using parenthesis I think it would help me use those operators with much more success. Thanks.

Comment: maybe are you talking about [Point Free Style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) ?. your function can be written as `((print . show) .) . take . snd` in point free style. however, abusing it will sometimes decrease readability.

Comment: "I understand that most haskellers typically use the (&) and (.) operators over parenthesis" --Did you mean `($)` rather than `(&)`? While there is a [`(&)` in `Data.Function`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-), and it could conceivably be used for what you are trying to do (it is just `flip ($)`), it is significantly rarer than `($)` in Haskell code out there.

Comment: @duplode Yes sorry, I meant the dollar sign ($) operator, not (&).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rewrite...

```
print . show . take (snd (1,5)) $ [1..10]
```

... is as good as it gets in terms of readability. The following suggestions will in fact make it more convoluted than necessary; still, knowing such things are possible can, as you say, bring a better appreciation of how `($)` and `(.)` work.

The first function which is applied to `[1..10]` is...

```
take (snd (1,5))
```

... so let's focus on it for a moment. If you were trying to eliminate parentheses there without the rest of the expression, you might end up with...

```
take . snd $ (1,5)
```

To reconstruct the original function, we need to apply that to `[1..10]`. A natural way of doing so would be...

```
(take . snd $ (1,5)) [1..10]
```

... but since we are avoiding parentheses, we need extra trickery. There are two immediate options. The first one is passing the list to the function with a `($)` section:

```
($ [1..10]) . take . snd $ (1,5)
```

Just like `(* 2)` is a function that takes a number and multiplies it by two, `($ [1..10])` is a function...

```
GHCi> :t ($ [1..10])
($ [1..10]) :: (Num t, Enum t) => ([t] -> b) -> b
```

... that takes a function and applies it to `[1..10]`. (And yes, I have just added a pair of parentheses; however, they are not really being used for grouping -- `($ [1..10])` is just alternative syntax for `flip ($) [1..10]` -- so I say they don't count :))

At this point, we can complete the expression in the same manner of your original version:

```
print . show . ($ [1..10]) . take . snd $ (1,5)
```

The other option is writing the whole function pointfree (that is, without explictly writing the arguments). To do that, let's get back to...

```
take . snd $ (1,5)
```

... and leave out the pair for a moment:

```
take . snd
```

`take . snd` is a function...

```
GHCi> :t take . snd
take . snd :: (a1, Int) -> [a] -> [a]
```

... that takes a pair and a list and gives back a list. We can, however, also read this type as:

```
take . snd :: (a1, Int) -> ([a] -> [a])
```

... that is, we have a function that takes a pair and returns a function. If we compose some function `foo` with `take . snd` so that we get `foo . take . snd`, `foo` will be applied to the function produced by `take . snd`. In fact, we have done just that when we used `($ [1..10])` just above. Besides supplying argments, another thing we can do with functions is composing them. And we do have an operator for composing functions...

```
((print . show) .) . take . snd
```

... namely, `(.)`. The weird expression within the parentheses is a section of `(.)`, just like the one we used for `($)` before, except that this is a left section, and that was a right section. Due to operator precedence shenanigans an extra pair of parentheses is necessary; equally unsatisfactory alternatives include...

```
(print .) . (show .) . take . snd
```

... and...

```
(.) print . (.) show . take . snd
```

With the pointfree function in our hands, we can supply the arguments in whichever way we feel like -- for instance, like this...

```
(((print . show) .) . take . snd) (1,5) [1..10]
```

... or this...

```
($ [1..10]) . ((print . show) .) . take . snd $ (1,5)
```

... or even this...

```
($ [1..10]) . ($ (1,5)) $ ((print . show) .) . take . snd
```

... or, for something less bizarre:

```
let f = ((print . show) .) . take . snd in f (1,5) [1..10]
```

There are indeed many alternatives -- and they all conspire to show how nice your original rewrite was in the first place!

Comment: Wow thank you for the comprehensive response! Answers my question perfectly :)

Answer (score 3):

Your final simplification is good and quite readable in the `f . g . h $ x` style. The main point of that style isn't so much to eliminate parentheses (though it can clean them up and sometimes eliminate them) but as an idiom to make it clear at a glance that a sequence of functions is being applied to something and what those functions are.

With expressions in high school algebra, sometimes you can't eliminate parentheses when you simplify because you're stuck with a fixed set of operators and with a fixed order of operations. That's why parentheses have to be included in high school algebra. If you're stuck with just `(.)` and `($)`, I think that's the best you can get.

### Eliminating parentheses by adding a new operator

This isn't recommended because your simplified version was just fine and people will have to take time to figure out what the new operator means for little benefit, but I'm adding it just for the sake of completeness.

We're in Haskell instead of high school algebra, so we can add a new operator with whatever precedence. It needs to work like `($)` but have a precedence equal to `(.)` (since it can't be greater than `(.)`, which has the highest precedence).

So, to eliminate all parentheses (except for the tuple) in `ghci`:

```hs
Prelude> let infixr 9 $$$; a $$$ b = a b
Prelude> print . show . take $$$ snd (1, 5) $ [1..10]
"[1,2,3,4,5]"
```

To eliminate all parentheses:

```hs
Prelude> let infixr 9 $$$; a $$$ b = a b
Prelude> let tuple :: a -> b -> (a, b); tuple = (,)
Prelude> print . show . take $$$ snd $$$ tuple 1 5 $ [1..10]
"[1,2,3,4,5]"
```