# Rewrite `map (f.g.h) x` with $ without parentheses?

Tags: haskell

I would like check whether we can't rewrite `map (f.g.h) x` with `$` without parentheses as I didn't find a way.

Here are my trials:

```
map (f.g.h) x
-> map (f.g.h) $ x  -- OK, no benefit
-> map $ f.g.h $ x  -- wrong as map doesn't take one parameter
-> (map $ f.g.h) x  -- Ok, no benefit, ugly :-)
```

Only elegant option I found was to use

```
negate . sum . tail <$> [[1..5], [3..6]]]
```

but I would like to be sure that I didn't skip some options above.
Thank you

Comment: What about `map f $ map g $ map h x`? I do not see how the `negate ...` part is relevant here?

Comment: One can also define a custom application operator, say `$$` with the right infix level, and left-associativity, so that `f $$ x $$ y $$ z` means `((f x) y) z`. I would however avoid that, and prefer parentheses.

Comment: `flip map x $ f . g . h` but that's ugly.

Comment: `x >>= return . f . g . h`? Then you don't need `($)` either :)

Comment: Related: [*How would I re-write this expression using the function composition (.) /application ($) operators?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42357394/2751851).

Answer (score 8):

how about?

```
let u = f.g.h in map u x
```

no parenthesis, no `$`

Answer (score 5):

If you define the function

```
map (f.g.h) x
```

You thus process *each* element of `x` with `f . g . h`, this means that we first apply `h` on it, then `g` on the result, and finally `f` on that result.

But we can also work with three separate `map`s, like:

```
map f $ map g $ map h x
```

Comment: > that is used as a trick to let Haskell write brackets implicitly

I really don't like this formulation. `$` is just the function application function (+ hacks which aren't relevant here), no need to bring brackets into this.